# DataFrame eval using function name in expression

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `df.eval` to evaluate an expression that contains a call to a function - in my example it's `numpy.around` which I have imported in the local namespace. According to the documentation, using `@` before the function name should do the trick, but it throws this error

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

What am I doing wrong? Doesn't work after fresh run, in IDE (Spyder / Jupyter notebook) or from console.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import around


df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.array([1.12,2.76])})

# this throws TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
df['y'] = df.eval('@around(x,1)')

# this works
df['z'] = around(df['x'],1)

print(pd.__version__)
# 0.23.4

print(np.__version__)
# 1.15.1

import sys
print(sys.version)
# 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: If you re-run that exact code afresh... does it work? I've just tried your exact code and it works fine...

Comment: @JonClements I can reproduce `numpy` 1.14.5, `pandas` 0.20.3

Comment: Works for me with pandas: 0.23.4 and numpy:1.15.1 although I wouldn't expect it not to have worked in earlier versions... Just wondering if there were floating variables/columns left over somehow from a previous run...

Comment: @JonClements https://pastebin.com/ZfyhqKPs and that's after a kernel restart so nothing can be left over

Comment: Bizarre... I get a DF of `{'x': {0: 1.12, 1: 2.76}, 'y': {0: 1.1, 1: 2.8}}` which looks correct...

Comment: @JonClements Added extra clarification ( code doesn't work even after fresh run) and numpy version. The funny thing is that it ran fine yesterday and I didn't update anything - I thought I was just distracted yesterday and didn't notice the error. I tried this on two computers (both Windows 10). one with fresh Anaconda install, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
The workaround is simpler, no need to remove `numexpr` package, just use a different parsing engine for the expression:

```
df['y'] = df.eval('@around(x,1)', engine = 'python')
```

**First answer**

I managed to find a workaround and I also figured out where the problem seems to be. First I updated `conda` itself and all packages (including `python` to 3.7.0, but I don't believe Python version is relevant). After that:

Step 1: remove `pandas` and `numpy`

```
conda remove pandas numpy

The following packages will be REMOVED:

    bokeh:        0.13.0-py37_0
    mkl_fft:      1.0.4-py37h1e22a9b_1
    mkl_random:   1.0.1-py37h77b88f5_1
    numba:        0.39.0-py37h830ac7b_0
    numexpr:      2.6.8-py37h9ef55f4_0
    numpy:        1.15.1-py37ha559c80_0
    pandas:       0.23.4-py37h830ac7b_0
    scikit-learn: 0.19.1-py37hae9bb9f_0
    scipy:        1.1.0-py37h4f6bf74_1
```

Step 2: reinstall only `pandas` and `numpy`

```
    conda install pandas numpy

    The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    mkl_fft:    1.0.4-py37h1e22a9b_1  
    mkl_random: 1.0.1-py37h77b88f5_1  
    numpy:      1.15.1-py37ha559c80_0  
    pandas:     0.23.4-py37h830ac7b_0
```

After step 2, the code worked as expected, so the problem must lie in one of the other packages removed.

Step 3: add each ofthe packages removed initially one by one (bokeh, numba, numexpr, scikit-learn, scipy) and test each time if the code still works. After installing `numexpr` the code failed, so that is where the problem is. Not sure how you could add `numpexpr` back again - I tried some older versions but everytime the code failed

Comment: Good bit of detective work. It's curious as I made an (obviously foolish) assumption that `.eval` required `numexpr` because it's required for `.query`... Checking `pd.get_versions()` I see I didn't have it installed and presumably why  your code worked in the virtualenv I was using. This kind of feels like it should be an issue on the pandas GH...